# Return JSON based on Persistent Query from yesod handler

Tags: json, haskell, yesod

this will be an additional question for @KonstantineRybnikov about [Return JSON from yesod handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17282501/return-json-from-yesod-handler).

What if i want have a Persistent Query specifically `selectList` and all the result data must return into a JSON format? what will be the code for it?

here is my code (Adopt from the code of @KonstantineRybnikov):

```
    -- JSON
    import           Data.Aeson      (object, (.=))
    import qualified Data.Aeson      as J
    import           Yesod.Core.Json (returnJson)

    getImagesR :: Handler Value
    getImagesR = do
          images <- runDB $ selectList [ImagesFilename !=. ""] [Desc ImagesDate]
          return $ object (if null images then [] else [] -- i want the result of my perstent to be in a JSON FORMAT)
```

``

hope you help me thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your main problem is that `selectList` returns a list of `Entity Record` (where `Record` is the type you are querying) instead of `Record`, so we'll have to get a list of records using `map entityVal` (`entityVal` is defined in [`Entity`](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.8/20140916-162/persistent/Database-Persist-Types.html#t:Entity)). You handler will look like this :

```
getImagesR = do
  images <- runDB $ selectList [ImagesFilename !=. ""] [Desc ImagesDate]
  returnJson (map entityVal images)
```

Now it's just a matter of transforming `[Record]` to JSON. Luckily, this can be done automatically by adding the word `json` to the persistent model definition ([as shown here](https://github.com/yesodweb/persistent/wiki/Persistent-entity-syntax#json-instances)).

Comment: Hi thank you for the response i copy you code and it works :-)

another question if you may - what if i use the ``rawSQL``?

Comment: Depending on how you use it, `rawSql` might return a list of `Entity`, in which case it will work exactly the same. Otherwise, I'm not sure, because it depends on what exactly you get back.

Comment: can i ask a follow up question.. i want to include the ``id`` how do i do that?

Comment: That's the other part of ``Record``. You can use ``entityKey`` to recover the ``Key``. Then the way to convert it to something usable depends on the backend you use. For example, for SQL, ``fromSqlKey```might do the trick.